# Compilation error when overriding a generic method with a type parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I am aware of type erasure but this doesn't make sense to me.

```
class Base{
   public <T> Collection<T> transform(Collection<T> list)
   { 
      return new ArrayList<T>(); 
   }
}
```

And

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override // compilation error
    public Collection<CharSequence> transform(Collection<CharSequence> list) {
        return new HashSet<CharSequence>();
    }
}
```

An error is generated in my IDE:

> 'transform(Collection)' in 'Derived' clashes with
>   'transform(Collection)' in 'Base'; both methods have the same erasure,
>   yet neither overrides the other

My thoughts were we could override `transform` without an error from the compiler.
Why `transform` in `Derived` does not correctly override the method `transform` in Base? I know It has to do with *type erasure* but. I can't understand why.

Comment: You need to give Base the same generic parameter, `T`, and then specify the concrete parameter in Derived.

Comment: This is not allowed! The following code would be possible, if it were allowed: `Base instance = new Derived(); Collection<Number> numbers = ...; Collection<Number> transformed = instance.transform(numbers);` But as you can see, you would call your derived class' transform method with a wrong argument.

Comment: Your method signature in the base class says that it allows *any* T, not a specific T.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of the method in the base class:

```
<T> Collection<T> transform(Collection<T> list)
```

says "I will accept a collection with elements of *any* type, and return you a collection of elements of that same type.

By the Liskov Substitution Principle, any subclass which implements this method must do the same. In particular, it must accept a collection with elements of any type.

If you try to override this with a method:

```
Collection<CharSequence> transform(Collection<CharSequence> list)
```

then it doesn't do what is required: it doesn't accept collection elements of any type, it only accepts elements of a *specific* type. Hence it doesn't override the superclass method

Normally, there is no problem with defining a method in a subclass which doesn't override a method in the superclass: you can define new methods in the subclass that don't exist in the superclass. But because of type erasure, you can't continue to have both methods, since they have the same signature. Hence, the compiler disallows you from doing this.

Answer (score 5):

`Base` and `Derived` are not generic classes and `Collection<T>` in `Base` has nothing to do with `Collection<CharSequence>` in `Derived` - there is no connection between them - hence an error!

You can fix it as follows:

```
class Base<T> {
    public Collection<T> transform(Collection<T> list) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base<CharSequence> {
    @Override
    public Collection<CharSequence> transform(Collection<CharSequence> list) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the valid override would be:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public <T> Collection<T> transform(Collection<T> list) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: And, if you wanted, you could make the return type `HashSet<CharSequence>` in `Derived` too, since that is covariant.